# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.inputcode.password')

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="mylogin()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="inputcode.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="inputcode.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
<br>
{{inputcode.password}}<---testing for correct syntax and it works fine here
```

Controller:

```
$scope.inputcode;
$scope.discountcodes=['phillyd','kevin','john'];

$scope.mylogin = function() {

    for (var i=0; i<$scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
      if($scope.inputcode.password==$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);
      }
      else{
        console.log("You failed to crack the code young jedi");
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

**Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.inputcode.password')**

I have already tested that $scope.inputcode.password is valid and holds information by showing the information on my html page with {{inputcode.password}}.

I don't understand what exactly is the error?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `$scope.inputcode` but not as an object - as it currently exists, it is just `undefined`. You need to initialise it as an object, like so:

```
$scope.inputcode = {};
```

This will allow you to evaluate it as an object.